# undefined method `permit' for "1":String - RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I fell a bit ridiculous but I really have no idea what this error is trying to tell me? I'm new to rspec and this is a new one for me. I'll post my code for clarity - ERROR: undefined method `permit' for "1":String|

CONTROLLER:

```
def subscriber_params
  params.require(:subscriber).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number)
end
```

SPEC:
      require "rails_helper"

```
describe SubscribersController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }

  it "creates a new comment" do
    sign_in(user)
    comment = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment)

    expect { post :create, subscriber: subscriber, comment: comment }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

ERROR:

[image]

Comment: Images are a horrible way to show error messages etc.

Comment: @FrederickCheung Noted thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }
```

to

```
let(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:subscriber) }
```

because you want to pass the subscriber's *attributes* to the request not an actually *instance* of a subscriber.